# fixed floating point calculations in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

In Java I need some hint to declare floating point variable that in all virtual machine run uniquely and show number unique float number in all machine ( mobile machine and PC )

Comment: Take a look at strictfp [here](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/newin12.html)

Comment: Could you clarify. Are you asking for a floating point value that is globally unique, i.e. not the same for any two VMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strictfp` keyword for class declaration or variables :

```
public strictfp class MyFPclass { 
    // ... contents of class here ...
}
```

The Java package java.lang.Math class contains these strictfp methods:

```
 public static strictfp double abs(double);
 public static strictfp int max(int, int);
 public static strictfp long max(long, long);
 public static strictfp float max(float, float);
 public static strictfp double max(double, double);
 public static strictfp int min(int, int);
```

Comment: It's been part of the language since JDK 1.2

Comment: In JDK8 there's no "strictfp" for listed methods in java.lang.StrictMath, but only for ```toRadians(double angdeg)``` and ```toDegrees(double angrad)```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 classes for this purpose you can think of

1. Math.random()
2. java.util.Random class

The methods of the Random class often produce random numbers in a more convenient form, but requires creating an object, which sometimes is inconvenient. In constrast, the Math.random() method produces a double value which must sometimes be translated and cast into the form you need it. It's a tradeoff between the globalness of Math.random more directly useful numbers from the Random class.